# Use resource from .aar library with android.nonTransitiveRClass = true

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, zoom-sdk

**About my case:**

I'm using **ZoomSDK** by adding .aar files (mobilertc.aar, commonlib.aar) into project.  In the `:app` module,  I use some resources from the file `mobilertc.aar` (like R.drawable.zm_transparent, R.layout.zm_rc_fingers_question,...)
My project use **Android Gradle Plugin 8.1** so `android.nonTransitiveRClass` is `true` as default so the resource files got `Unresolved reference` error.

If I set `android.nonTransitiveRClass` is `false` in the `gradle.properties` file, my code works well, those errors gone. But the output apk size is too big so I want to keep enabling `nonTransitiveRClass` for my project.

**My question:**
How can I reference to resource files in `.aar` library with `android.nonTransitiveRClass = true`

Comment: You have to give complete path from mobilertc module. 
com.zoom.mobile.R.drawable.zm_transparent .. Please use correct package name

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But I can't find out package name of the R class of the .aar file. mobilertc is .aar file, not a normal module

Comment: since you have mobilertc.aar file in your project ( libs folder) and added their implementation in build.gradle file, you can call their class.

Can you add code where you have called any of method from mobilertc aar file?

Comment: Not really, I can access methods, variables, everything that public and written in kotlin/java in libs but not the resources. I found out I can access resources from mobile.aar file in XML code but not from java or kotlin code. My kotlin code accessing resources in .aar file is quite simple: `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zm_rc_drawer)` `inflater.inflate(R.layout.zm_rc_float_view, this)`

Comment: Those codes got `Unresolved reference` errors when compiling. But in `:app` XML files, I can use these files like `<include layout="@layout/zm_rc_float_view"/>`

Comment: something like that
setBackgroundResource(us.zoom.sdk.R.drawable.zm_rc_drawer)
inflater.inflate(us.zoom.sdk.R.layout.zm_rc_float_view, this)

I am not sure in which package this file is..  us.zoom.sdk is basically package name where this exists. You can cross check this package name

Comment: yeah, maybe I should change the question to `How to find out package name of R class from .aar file`. I tried `us.zoom.sdk` but it doesnt work